# How does the command prompt know where to find the requested compiler/interpreter?

Tags: shell

When compiling/interpreting a program from the command prompt, how does the command prompt know where to find the requested compiler/interpreter?
Are these files stored in a specific place or something like that? I'm just about getting a hang of high-level programming, but I find it pretty hard to wrap my head around what happens under the hood.

Comment: This is not related to programming languages at all (and certainly it`s not compiler construction). It's just the console program having a list of directories to search for any entered program name. What OS and shell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts: Where to find the file just from it's filename, and what to do with it.

**Where files (programs) are searched if just the name is entered:**

**Windows (CMD):**
There is a variable `%PATH%` which has a list of `;`-separated directories, eg. `C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C.\somethingelse`. It is saved somewhere in the registry and can be set either in CMD itself or with a GUI somewhere in the OS configs.

**Linux etc. (Bash and many more):**
Similar, there is a variable `$PATH` which can be set at least in the shell and various config files, and the entries are separated by `:`, eg. `/bin:/usr/bin/even/more`. Priority is from left to right.

Additionally, some shells (eg. Bash) cache lookup results in their own implementation-specific way (depending on the configuration), because it's faster than having to check every directory in the path variable (at least if the searched program is in the last dir, everything has to be checked).

**What to do with the file once it's found:**

**Windows:**
In Windows, everything works with the filename suffix.
`.exe` and some others are native programs to start.
`.bat` is a shell script which is executed like it's manually written to the shell.

For every other suffix, it's configurable which program belongs to the suffix (stored in the registry, how to comfortably change it depends heavily on the used Windows version). Eg. you could say that `.py` belongs to your Python interpreter, the a file foo.py will start the interpreter. Btw., the same suffix-program configuration is usen when a file is double-clicked in the GUI file explorer, and of course program installers can add their entries too without the user having to do it.

**Linux:**
For Linux, the suffix is not as important. The first relevant thing is a binary (yes/no) flag `x` (x like e**x**ecutable) which exists for each file on the file system, just like file name, creation timestamp etc.etc.

*If the x flag is set to yes:*
Linux tries to detect what kind of program it is from the content. The difference between a native compiled binary program and a not-compiled script of some scripting language is pretty clear.

A native linux program is started by the kernel, like expected. Additional binary program types could be configured, eg. there is the Wine software which runs some Windows programs on Linux, and one could add a specification how Windows exe`s can be recognized inside and that they should be started with Wine.

For a text file with the x flag, the next step is to look at the first line, which should start with a '#!' (called shebang), followed by the path of the interpreter (eg. `#!/bin/bash)`. Shell scripts (like the bat files on Windows) are realized this way, but it's not limited to classical shell scripts: Nothing prevents anyone from making a `#!/bin/python` script which Python content (of course, Python has to be installed for this to work).

*If the x flag is set to no:*
Shells like bash with usual configuration won't do anything, independent if it is a real program just without flag or a jpg image etc. For the GUI file managers:
Again, the content (and possibly the file name suffix too) is inspected to get the type, like jpg images, mp3 music, C++ source code etc.etc. (Linux knows pretty many types), and then the fitting program is looked up in a list configurable by the user and/or program installations (mime file type id <-> program).

...

Note that in the case of eg. Python scripts (which are just normal text files, not something for the kernel to work with), it can be done with and without x flag: With flag and a shebang line, or without flag and a matching mime list entry. In the "without flag" case, the shebang won't hurt if it is there, because Python (and many other scripting languages) consider it a comment because of the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding interpreters on unix-based systems, lots of scripts start with a so-called shebang or hashbang (`#!` on the first line of the script) that tells what interpreter to invoke, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29 .

Answer (score 0):

When you enter something like `some-program some-arguments`, the shell will look through each directory listed in the environment variable `$PATH` for an executable file named `some-program` (on Windows it's `%PATH%` and `some-program.exe`).

This is not specific to compilers and interpreters - it happens whether `some-program` is `gcc`, `python`, `firefox` or `notepad`.